# How to set the text in the QComboBox to align to the center without making it editable in PyQt

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt, alignment, center

I have found that doing

```
self.combo.setEditable(True)
self.combo.lineEdit().setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

will align the text in the combobox to the center. But as soon as i do that , the styling that i have applied to the combobox doesn't work and the text that shows inside it will the default plain text . Also i don't want to make it editable and i dont like the GUI effect that occurs when we set it to editable.

Is there an easy way to center align the text and yet retain the same GUI effects as before (like style and behaviour on clicking it) ?

Comment: i have even tried setting the combobox to read only . But that doesn't help

Comment: There is no way other than reimplement `paintEvent()` method

Comment: it would be very helpful of you if u provide a small code snippet to do something like a bold text with that method...anyway i will look into the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reimplement combobox drawing routine by yourself this way (snippet from project I'm working on):

```
class CustomComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
    ...

    def paintEvent(self, evt):
        painter = QtGui.QStylePainter(self)
        painter.setPen(self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Text))
        option = QtGui.QStyleOptionComboBox()
        self.initStyleOption(option)
        painter.drawComplexControl(QtGui.QStyle.CC_ComboBox, option)
        textRect = QtGui.qApp.style().subControlRect(QtGui.QStyle.CC_ComboBox, option, QtGui.QStyle.SC_ComboBoxEditField, self)
        painter.drawItemText(
            textRect.adjusted(*((2, 2, -1, 0) if self.isShown else (1, 0, -1, 0))),
            QtGui.qApp.style().visualAlignment(self.layoutDirection(), QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft),
            self.palette(), self.isEnabled(),
            self.fontMetrics().elidedText(self.currentText(), QtCore.Qt.ElideRight, textRect.width())
        )

   ...
```

`painter.drawItemText` call is where text is being drawn.